# Secure SSL Enabled JMS (HornetQ) Connection using Spring

Tags: spring, ssl, jms, hornetq, spring-jms

I am pretty new to JMS and was able to create a connection to the server and receive JMS Messages. However now I wish to add SSL support to it and I a facing issues. Can someone tell me what should I do, below is the code for a regular non-SSL connection. I can set the keystore and truststore seperately using System.setProperty (javax.net.ssl.keyStore, javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword, javax.net.ssl.trustStore, javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword). However this code needs some SSL enabling which I am missing.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jndi.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${java.naming.provider.url}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${java.naming.factory.initial}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">${java.naming.factory.url.pkgs}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">$java.naming.security.principal}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${java.naming.security.credentials}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref ="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
    <property name="deliveryMode" value="2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="ACS_BOOT"/>
</bean>

<!-- Listener Asynchronous -->
<bean id="acsBootListener" class="com.viasat.nbn.nms.acsjmssubscriber.AcsBootListener"/>

<jms:listener-container concurrency="5-10">
             <jms:listener destination="ACS_BOOT" ref="acsBootListener"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you would need to change something in the Spring configuration code. [This sample](https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/tree/master/examples/jms/ssl-enabled) from HornetQ suggests the changes are at HornetQ level, more specifically the connection factory uses a different connector.

Comment: @AndreiStefan aren't these server side config files? I am writing a client for exactly this setup.